# 403 trying to sign provided bytes: The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

POM file detail:

```
      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-appengine</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

1.2.4.RELEASE

Libs included in jar:
Line 643: Step #0: [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/0.21.1/google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.21.1.pom
Line 643: Step #0: [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/0.21.1/google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.21.1.pom

## Environment details

- OS: Debian
- Java version: 11
- google-auth-library-java version(s): 0.21.1

## Steps to reproduce

- upload a file in GCS bucket.
- Try to download it using code given below.
  Stacktrace

```
com.google.auth.ServiceAccountSigner$SigningException: Failed to sign the provided bytes
at com.google.auth.oauth2.IamUtils.sign(IamUtils.java:87)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.sign(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:361)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.signUrl(StorageImpl.java:772)
at com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.signUrl(Blob.java:822)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error code 403 trying to sign provided bytes: The caller does not have permission
at com.google.auth.oauth2.IamUtils.getSignature(IamUtils.java:125)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.IamUtils.sign(IamUtils.java:84)
... 69 more
```

Code snippet

```
// [START auth_cloud_explicit_compute_engine]
public Storage authCompute() throws IOException {
// Explicitly request service account credentials from the compute engine
// instance.
//GoogleCredentials credentials = ComputeEngineCredentials.create();
GoogleCredentials credentials = ComputeEngineCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

    System.out.println("Buckets:");
    Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
    for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
        System.out.println(bucket.toString());
    }
    return storage;
}
// [END auth_cloud_explicit_compute_engine]
Storage storage = authUtil.authCompute();
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName));
return blob.signUrl(urlExpirationTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

My application is deployed on GKE. From there we are trying to download/get signed url a file i.e. stored in GCS.

Comment: It seems to be a permissions error for the account you are using to access the storage bucket. As far as I can see you are using the default service account for GKE to access the bucket. Please verify if the service account you are using has proper permissions to reach the bucket by either IAM or an ACL on the bucket.

Comment: GCP service account bind with gke account as admin permission. We are able to upload files but not able to download it or to get signed url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ComputeEngineCredentials uses IAM sign blob API call so the service account being used needs to have the iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission. Depending on your setup, this may be the default service account for the GKE or a workload identity.

Comment: You are the best. Why is (or where??) is this not properly documented? How did you find out yourself?

Answer (score 1):

IAM Service Account Credentials API this api also needs to be enabled along with service account token creator access.

Comment: Great answer. This was the key for me.  I added the permissions [Firebase mentions in its docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#service_account_does_not_have_required_permissions) but that wasn't working.  With that API enabled, it does.